# Python 2d-histogram success rate per bin

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have data in arrays x, y and w where 'x' and 'y' indicate position and 'w' is a weight of either 1 or 0 indicating success or failure. I'm trying to create a 2d histogram where each bin of the histogram is coloured based on the percentage of successes in that bin (i.e. # of successes in bin divided by total points in bin). I've played around with numpy.histogram2d quite a bit and can get density plots going, but this is not the same as the % of success scheme I'm aiming for. Please note normed=True in the numpy.histogram2d argument does not alleviate this problem.

(To clarify on the difference, a density plot would indicate large 'colour value' if there is a larger number of successes in the bin regardless of how many failures are in the same bin. I would like to have the percentage of successes instead, so a large number of failures in the same bin would give a smaller 'colour value'. I apologise for poor terminology).

Thank you very much to anyone who can help!

Example of current code that doesn't do what I'm aiming for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.figure(1)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50, weights=w, normed=True)
extent = [yedges[0], yedges[-1], xedges[-1], xedges[0]]
plt.imshow(H, extent=extent,interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this works, but you don't give data, so it's hard to check. `normed=True` gives you densities, if you don't pass `normed=True`, you get weighted sample counts, so if you divide your weighted version (which is really just #successes per bin) by unweighted (# of elements in each bin), you'll end up with % successes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.figure(1)
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50, weights=w)
H2, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x,y, bins=50)
extent = [0,1, xedges[-1], xedges[0]]
plt.imshow(H/H2, extent=extent,interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

This could leave `nan` in the final histogram, so you might want to make a decision for those cases.

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm. Thank you very much! I actually used the underscores as written above, do you mind explaining what these do (my assumption is that it allows calculation of H2 without recalculating xedges and yedges).

Comment: @Dr.Jones It doesn't do anything special...the ouput of np.histogram2d is a tuple with three elements; however, the _ is often used when unpacking to indicate that you don't care about that element. xedges and yedges don't change based on the weights, so it doesn't really matter to keep them again. To really see this work, try something like `lst = [1,2,3]; a,b,c = lst; print b; print c; d,b,b = lst; print b;` (hard to show when you can't do multiline) but basically what happens is that you assign to b twice and only the last assignment stays.